# How to get view html in controller cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to send a view in the email body, I have used the below code to get the html:
    "tech_comm_email" this is my view.

```
$this->set('comm_roles', $techid);
$this->set('techid', $techid);
$this->set('orders', $orders);
$html = $this->render('tech_comm_email');
```

When I print `$html` I didn't get the html and the html is show in the browser.

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Anyone have any idea.

Comment: Any **special** reason you are using CakePHP 1.3 ? Why not you use CakePHP 3.* As you know this version is outdated as mentioned in CakePHP manual : _This document is for a version of CakePHP that is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a newer release!_ [Link](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/)